# Azure SDK Help : How can I pull the information about the last services accessed by user?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

In azure, there are multiple services like audit logs, azure access advisor but none of them provides exactly the information I need.  How to get any of the below information for azure users:

1. Last services accessed list by the user. (which services are accessed by the user in past and which services are still unused but he has the permission to access them).
2. Detailed last services accessed data(what services are accessed by which azure user and when was it last accessed).

PS: by access, I mean any type of access: Be it read operation or write operation or update operation or any other operation specific to the service.

In AWS there is this thing:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor.html.

can anyone help if there is something similar to this is present in azure as well?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by `accessed services`.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri, I have added multiple changes to the question and added more details to it. Please have a look into it now. Thanks for pointing things out

Comment: Thanks. I don't think you will be able to view information about read operations. In any case, I see multiple questions in your question. Please break them into separate questions (may 1 & 2 together and 3 as a separate question).

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri, thanks for the information, I have added one link of 'Refining permissions in AWS using last accessed information' which is there on AWS, looking for something similar in azure.